# How does Yahoo break out of an iFrame without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

For some reason, even if I disable javascript, Yahoo still breaks out.

here's an example: https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym&.intl=us

How do they do that?

Comment: You mean the response header X-Frame-Options DENY that prevent it from displaying in an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set header to: `X-Frame-Options:DENY`